# du command showing different results than st_blocks

Tags: files, filesystems, disk-usage, c

I'm implementing `du -a` in C and I'm using the `stat` function for this. The problem is that what I get from using `st_blocks` is 2× what I get when I use the command itself, does this make any sense? or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please add more details, such as a copy of the code you're writing, the output it gives, and the output you're expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) counts 512-byte blocks in `st_blocks`, whereas [`du`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html) counts 1024-byte blocks by default (in most Linux distributions) — so it's perfectly normal to get twice the number of blocks from `stat`.

([POSIX `du`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html) counts 512-byte blocks too; GNU `du` follows that standard if you set `POSIXLY_CORRECT`.)